# Navigating attributes tables with arrows keys in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, fields-attributes, shortcuts

In QGIS 3.24.1 I am trying to navigate through attributes quickly using the arrows keys on the keyboard, as I was doing on previous versions. Unfortunately, QGIS is trying to make the number in the cell go up (or down).

Does anybody has a solution to make QGIS works as in the previous version, where by precision the down arrow the selection goes from attributes to attributes, by staying in the column I'm working on ?

For example here, going from modifying the 6th "diameter" cell to the 7th, etc.

[image: as seen in this picture]

Answer (score 2):

Toggle editing mode: if you are in no-editing mode, you can navigate with <kbd>arrow up/down</kbd> without changing the content of the cell.

If you want to stay in edit mode, press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> then <kbd>arrow down</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - <kbd>arrow down</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - <kbd>arrow down</kbd> etc.

Comment: That's really not practical, I don't understand why they changed how this worked, it was perfect before. Makes it quite hard to edit/add data rapidly, even with your ENTER trick.Thanks for your answer ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could change the widget type from "Range" to "Text edit" in layer's Properties -> Attributes Form. You should modify the form type from "Autogenerate" to "Drag and Drop Designer" and change the widget type for integer fields.[image]